# Tortoise SVN in not working with Netbeans 11

Tags: svn, netbeans

I installed Netbeans 11 but when I committed a code there is an error. But TortoiseSVN works fine with netbeans 8.2.

[image]

Comment: As per the error you get, you need SVN clien version 1.8 or later... do you have that?

Comment: Thank you npinti.My tortoise version is 1.12.

Comment: What is the response when you submit **svn --version** from the command line?

Comment: @aysegulP same here for me for regular subversion. SVN version 1.10.0. I am suspecting it is because my jre and jdk are still at 8 and Netbeans 11 may need jre11+

Comment: I download slik subversion instead of tortoise. I don't know why but it works.

Comment: @aysegulP has not enabled the "command line client tools" option during the installation of TortoiseSVN

Answer (score 6):

You need re-run the TortoiseSVN installer (or during the TortoiseSVN installation) and select the option "command line client tools". I have made a screenshot of the option that appears during installation:

[image: command line client tools - Installation option]

Enabling this option netbeans 11.1 starts detecting SVN.

Comment: Thank you, it really worked out. And there's no need to install Subversion!